# How to find this $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i\backslash A_{i+1})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_{i+1} \subseteq A_i$. Then I want to find this
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i\backslash A_{i+1})=??$$
I try to do that by this way
\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i\backslash A_{i+1})=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_{i}\cap (A_{i+1})^c)&=(A_1 \cap {A_2}^c) \cup(A_2 \cap {A_3}^c) \cup (A_3 \cap {A_4}^c) \cup \cdots\\
&=A_1 \cap ({A_2}^c \cup A_2) \cap ({A_3}^c \cup A_3) \cap ({A_4}^c \cup A_4) \cap \cdots\\
&=A_1 \cap A_1 \cap A_1 \cap \cdots\\
&=A_1
\end{align*}
Is it right if I think ${A_i}^c \cup A_i=A_1$ for $i=2,3,4,\cdots$?

I am not sure about that way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might conjecture what the set is, then prove it by showing $B \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq B$.  For intuition to come up with a conjecture, why not take the case of a finite union?

Comment: Your third equality is not clear to me. The point where you say $(A_1 \cap {A_2}^c) \cup(A_2 \cap {A_3}^c) \cup (A_3 \cap {A_4}^c) \cup \cdots
=A_1 \cap ({A_2}^c \cup A_2) \cap ({A_3}^c \cup A_3) \cap ({A_4}^c \cup A_4) \cap \cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

If by $A_i^c$ you mean $A_1\setminus A_i$, then yes, $A_i\cup A_i^c=A_1$. However, the step in which you shifted the parentheses is not legitimate: in general

$$(S_1\cap S_2)\cup(S_3\cap S_4)\cup(S_5\cap\ldots\ne S_1\cap(S_2\cup S_3)\cap(S_4\cup S_5)\cap\ldots\;.$$

You would probably find it helpful to draw some Venn diagrams and to see what$\bigcup_{i=1}^n(A_i\setminus A_{i+1})$ looks like for some small $n$. However, I'll give you a hint. Let $C=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$; if $x\in C$, is $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty(A_i\setminus A_{i+1})$?

Answer (score 1):

You have already conjectured that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty (A_i\setminus A_{i+1})=A_1$. To disprove this, let us consider an example:

Let $A_i$ be the open interval $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$. Clearly, $A_{i+1}\subseteq A_i$. Also $0\in A_1$ but $0\not\in A_i\setminus A_{i+1}$ for any $i$. Hence $0\not\in \cup_{i=1}^\infty (A_i\setminus A_{i+1})$. It follows that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty (A_i\setminus A_{i+1})\ne A_1$.

So your conjecture was wrong. Based on the above example, now you can make a new conjecture:

$$\cup_{i=1}^\infty (A_i\setminus A_{i+1})= A_1\setminus \cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i.$$

Hint: Try chasing elements.